# Error converting view pager details to json

Tags: java, android, json, android-fragments

I successfully got a Viewpager working with help [from this tutorial: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-viewpager-gallery-images-and-texts-tutorial/]

Now, I'm trying to converting the data in the viewpager to date retrieved from a json file on a website. I have used the code to retrieve a regular list and it works fine but a problem I can't pinpoint with the ViewPager's adapter is causing this error:

```
Error:(159, 31) error: constructor ViewPagerAdapter in class ViewPagerAdapter cannot be applied to given types;
required: Context,String[],String[],String[],int[]
found: Activity,ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>,String,String,String,String
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Here's the code in the fragment:

```
public class WhatsHotFragment extends Fragment {

private TextView DateView;
private ImageView PhotoView;
private TextView whereView;
private TextView infoView;

ViewPager viewPager;
PagerAdapter adapter;


public WhatsHotFragment() {}



private static final String TAG_OS = "results";

private static final String where = "name";
private static final String date = "dates";
private static final String information = "info";
private static final String flag = "avatar_url";



ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


private static String url = "http://celebirious.com/bey/data/style.json";



JSONArray android = null;


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);



}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_whats_hot, null);

    oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    new JSONParse().execute();

    return v;

}

class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        infoView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.info);
        whereView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.where);
        DateView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.date);
        PhotoView = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.photo);
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        return json;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        try {

            android = json.getJSONArray(TAG_OS);
            for(int i = 0; i < android.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = android.getJSONObject(i);


                // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                String infoView = c.getString(information);
                String dateView = c.getString(date);
                String whereView = c.getString(where);
                String PhotoView = c.getString(flag);


                // Adding value HashMap key => value

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put(information, infoView);
                map.put(date, dateView);
                map.put(whereView, where);
                map.put(PhotoView, flag);


                oslist.add(map);

                viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);
                adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity(), oslist, where, date, information, flag);

                viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



}





 }
```

And in the ViewPagerAdapter, here's the code:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
// Declare Variables
Context context;
String[] where;
String[] date;
String[] information;
int[] flag;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, String[] where, String[] date,
        String[] information, int[] flag) {
    this.context = context;
    this.where = where;
    this.date = date;
    this.information = information;
    this.flag = flag;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return where.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    // Declare Variables
    TextView txtrank;
    TextView txtcountry;
    TextView txtpopulation;
    ImageView imgflag;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.styledeets, container,
            false);

    // Locate the TextViews in viewpager_item.xml
    txtrank = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
    txtcountry = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.where);
    txtpopulation = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.info);

    // Capture position and set to the TextViews
    txtrank.setText(where[position]);
    txtcountry.setText(date[position]);
    txtpopulation.setText(information[position]);

    // Locate the ImageView in viewpager_item.xml
    imgflag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.photo);
    // Capture position and set to the ImageView
    imgflag.setImageResource(flag[position]);

    // Add viewpager_item.xml to ViewPager
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);

    return itemView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);

}
}
```

My guess is this:
        public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, String[] where, String[] date,
            String[] information, int[] flag) {
        this.context = context;
        this.where = where;
        this.date = date;
        this.information = information;
        this.flag = flag;
    }

From the adapter is causing the problem - How could it be fixed, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your ViewPagerAdapter  class has a constructor that asks for Context context, String[] where, String[] date, String[] information, int[] flag -

```
public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, String[] where, String[] date,
        String[] information, int[] flag) {
    this.context = context;
    this.where = where;
    this.date = date;
    this.information = information;
    this.flag = flag;
}
```

But you are giving `Activity,ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>,String,String,String,String`

You should change the constructor to -

```
public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> map ,String s1,String s2,String s3,String s4) {
        ///implementation
    }
```

More.

You should change this line of code, now it is in the for loop, that means that you are doing this operation on each iteration, put it outside of the forloop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < android.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = android.getJSONObject(i);


            // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
            String infoView = c.getString(information);
            String dateView = c.getString(date);
            String whereView = c.getString(where);
            String PhotoView = c.getString(flag);


            // Adding value HashMap key => value

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put(information, infoView);
            map.put(date, dateView);
            map.put(whereView, where);
            map.put(PhotoView, flag);


            oslist.add(map);

            viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);
            adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity(), oslist, where, date, information, flag);

            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


        }
```

Even More:

AsyncTask - don't use this, it will give you problems if the activity is lost before the operation is complete. Check out Retrofit or/and Okhttp, or atleast use AsyncTaskLoader. And for Json manipulations, check out Gson or Jackson libraries.

Comment: Thanks for attempting to help me. The error still persists :( What do you mean by "outside of the forloop" ?

Comment: "Error:(27, 82) error: <identifier> expected" is the response for  public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>,where,date,information,flag) {

Comment: @HalesEnchanted You are setting - 
adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity(), oslist, where, date, information, flag);
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter); On each loop, put it outside - after your catch{}. There is no need to do it more than once.

Comment: You should give names for parameters where -> String where; ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> -> ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> map;

public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> map ,String s1,String s2,String s3,String s4) {
        ///implementation
    }

Comment: Hey, thanks! You said to look into Gson, I'm attempting to right now. Would that reduce the messiness of my code?

Comment: @HalesEnchanted
Check out this site - http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ It will make Java classes from json, and then you can use Gson like -
Gson gson = new Gson();
YourObject object = gson.fromJson(yourJsonString,YourObject.class)

Comment: It works with with any String or Stream, check out Okhttp for easy network operations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78964/discussion-between-halesenchanted-and-attels).