# From Json To ViewPager

Tags: java, android, json, android-fragments, gson

I'm trying to pass data from a json file to a viewpager. I have followed most of the advice previously given to me  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30448667/error-converting-view-pager-details-to-json)  but it returns blank, without even crashing.

The four files involved in this:
1. The main fragment:

```
 public class FashionFeed  extends Fragment {


ViewPager viewPager;
PagerAdapter adapter;

ThePagerAdapter newdapter;


public static final String URL =
        "http://celebirious.com/bey/data/space.json";


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_whats_hot, null);


    // Locate the ViewPager in viewpager_main.xml
    viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pager);

    viewPager.setClipToPadding(false);
    viewPager.setPadding(4, 0, 4, 0);

    int margin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20 * 2, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    viewPager.setPageMargin(-margin);

    new SimpleTask().execute(URL);


    return v;

}

private class SimpleTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Create Show ProgressBar
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls)   {
        String result = "";
        try {

            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);

            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (statusCode == 200) {
                InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                        (new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result += line;
                }
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        return result;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String jsonString)  {
        showData(jsonString);
    }
}

private void showData(String jsonString) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Style style = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Style.class);
    List<Space> space = style.getSpace();


    newdapter = new ThePagerAdapter(getActivity(), space);
    viewPager.setAdapter(newdapter);

}


}
```

The Adapter extending the Pager:

```
    public class ThePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    List<Space> list;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
     Context context;

      @Override
     public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
    }

     @Override
     public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return false;
     }

    public ThePagerAdapter(Context context,List<Space> list) {
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context; // red as well

    }

      @Override
     public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    // Declare Variables
    TextView txtrank;
    TextView txtcountry;
    TextView txtpopulation;
    ImageView imgflag;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.styledeets, container,
            false);

    // Locate the TextViews in viewpager_item.xml
    txtrank = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
    txtcountry = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.where);
    txtpopulation = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.info);

    // Capture position and set to the TextViews
    txtrank.setText(list.get(position).getName());
    txtcountry.setText(list.get(position).getDates());
    txtpopulation.setText(list.get(position).getInfo());


    String url = (list.get(position).getAvatarUrl());

    imgflag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.photo);


    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(url)
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_gmail)
            .fit()
            .tag(context)
            .into(imgflag);


    // Locate the ImageView in viewpager_item.xml
    // Capture position and set to the ImageView
    //imgflag.setImageResource(flag[position]);

    // Add viewpager_item.xml to ViewPager
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);

    return itemView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    // Remove viewpager_item.xml from ViewPager
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);

}

}
```

Gson data retreived from jsonschema2pojo.org:

Space.java

```
public class Space {

@Expose
private String name;
@Expose
private String dates;
@Expose
private String type;
@Expose
private String social;
@Expose
private String info;
@SerializedName("avatar_url")
@Expose
private String avatarUrl;

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The name
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 *
 * @param name
 * The name
 */
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The dates
 */
public String getDates() {
    return dates;
}

/**
 *
 * @param dates
 * The dates
 */
public void setDates(String dates) {
    this.dates = dates;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The type
 */
public String getType() {
    return type;
}

/**
 *
 * @param type
 * The type
 */
public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The social
 */
public String getSocial() {
    return social;
}

/**
 *
 * @param social
 * The social
 */
public void setSocial(String social) {
    this.social = social;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The info
 */
public String getInfo() {
    return info;
}

/**
 *
 * @param info
 * The info
 */
public void setInfo(String info) {
    this.info = info;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The avatarUrl
 */
public String getAvatarUrl() {
    return avatarUrl;
}

/**
 *
 * @param avatarUrl
 * The avatar_url
 */
public void setAvatarUrl(String avatarUrl) {
    this.avatarUrl = avatarUrl;
}
```

Lastly, Style.java

```
 public class Style {

@Expose
private List<Space> space = new ArrayList<Space>();

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The space
 */
public List<Space> getSpace() {
    return space;
}

/**
 *
 * @param space
 * The space
 */
public void setSpace(List<Space> space) {
    this.space = space;
}

 }
```

All the xml data is properly linked 'cause this all works when it is retrieving data locally. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out !!!!! How silly of me.

Was

```
 @Override
 public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
return false;
 }
```

should have been:

```
@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
}
```